# ASP.NET Core UseFileServer and redirect on 404

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm using the following code to embed a SPA in a C# library to be used in ASP.NET Core applications.

```
public static IApplicationBuilder UseSharedUI(this IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseFileServer(new FileServerOptions
    {
        RequestPath = "/shared-ui",
        FileProvider = new ManifestEmbeddedFileProvider(assembly: Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Builder)), "UI/dist"),
    });

    return app;
}
```

This works and when I run the API I can access the SPA under the `/shared-ui` route. But when I do a refresh in the browser in a route like `/shared-ui/analytics`, I get a 404 error, because the application doesn't know how to handle the subroute, it should fallback to the SPA to handle it.

I tried adding the following code, but the behavior is the same.

```
    app.MapWhen((context) => context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/shared-ui"), (appBuilder) =>
    {
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        appBuilder.UseRouting();
        appBuilder.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("/shared-ui/index.html");
        });
    });
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: You might want to take a look at this documentation. This is specific for when hosting a SPA with ASP.NET Core: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/spa-services?view=aspnetcore-5.0#routing-helpers-configuration

Comment: Thanks, but actually, this is not related. I'm not developing the SPA with the application neither serving it. I'm embedding the built SPA in a Nuget package, and this is what is making it difficult to setup properly.

Comment: No need to use .MapWhen(), you may use `endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("shared-ui/{**slug}", "shared-ui/index.html")`

Comment: And yes, MapFallbackToFile does not work for files outside wwwroot (i.e. with FileProvider specified), and there is no such option in StaticFileOptions. I guess it is possible to serve index.html directly via Response inside StaticFileOptions.OnPrepareResponse handler